# How to use multiline modifier of ssed (Super sed)?

Tags: sed

I came across this tool called ssed which supports Perl's regex mode and is a heavily enhanced version of sed: https://launchpad.net/ssed/

This command does not seem to work:

```bsh
printf 'a\nBc\n' | ssed -R 's/a(?m)\nBc\n/X\n/'
```

I expected the output to be:

```
X
```

But it prints:

```
a
Bc
```

I know I can use perl for multiline processing but I want to currently explore the option available with ssed.

EDIT:
This is from the launchpad page:

```
(7) Perl-style regular expressions, with examples. Use the -R switch.
    Used in /addressing/ or the FIND side of s/// commands.

  (?i)abc - case-insensitive match of abc, ABC, aBc, ABc, etc.
  ab(?i)c - same as above; the (?i) applies throughout the pattern
  (ab(?i)c) - matches abc or abC; the outer parens make the difference!
  (?m) - multi-line pattern space: same as "s/FIND/REPL/M"
```

Note: I am trying to simulate this perl command

```bsh
 seq 10 | perl -p0e 's/\n/:/g'
```

Output:

```
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:
```

Comment: I assume that nothing has changed in the basic function of `ssed` (except that Perl's regular expressions syntax was added) and the line break is still not part of the current line.

Comment: Cyrus, I think so too. I have added the info from their launchpad page..Correct me if I have used wrong syntax.

Comment: I get same result using sed. If you didn't feed the ssed with an 'X' in the printf input statement, why would you expect a 'X' on the output?

Comment: printf 'a\nBc\n' | perl -p0e  's/a(?m)\nBc\n/X\n/' I expected it to behave similar to this perl command, which outputs 'X\n'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But before you start matching you have to have the multiline pattern space in place-- that can only happen with N/G/H commands. Right now the pattern space is one line at a time.

Ssed is not perl in the garb of sed, but just the regex capabilities of Perl are implemented in it. As for Perl -0pe command is concerned you can try if the -z option is available otherwise you could always do

```
seq 10 |
ssed -e '
  :loop
  $!{
    N
    b loop
  }
  G
  s/\n/:/g
'
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:
```

Working:

- N command appends the next line to the pattern space.
- In a loop we apply the N command and so very soon all the lines are in the pattern space and each delimited by the next one via a newline.
- Then when the file is exhausted , meaning we have arrived at the eof, we substitute each newline with a colon.
- The G command appends the hold space to pattern space, meaning a newline is appended to the pattern space.

Note since no Perl style regexes were involved here, so no need for the -R option.
But the pattern space is multiline as we have read in the whole data into the pattern space. Meaning, you could now experiment with the Perl style regexes on this pattern space.

Comment: I am aware of N command, but what I want is to consider entire stream as one string and do regex replacement like the perl command I have now mentioned in my question description. I thought ssed is capable of that since it supports perl extension.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how your command works?

Comment: Added a brief description in words.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..spent a lot of time in learning sed.  And this is just amazing. Thanks.